# $(H,*)$ group with some properties $\Rightarrow H$ not an interval.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, real-numbers

> Let $(H, \ast)$ be a group, where $H \subseteq (0, \infty)$, which has these properties:
>
> - $x \in H \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} \in H$
> - $2023 \in H$, and
> - $x \ast y = \frac{1}{x} \ast \frac{1}{y}$ for any $x, y$.
>
> Prove that $H$ is not an interval.

As far as my attempts go, I haven't been able to do much, apart from modifying the " * " relation a bit and finding things such as x=1/x * 1/e=1/e * 1/x and so on.(where e is the identity element)

I could see an outline of what im supposed to prove, as if i were to take any value, either higher or lower than 2023 and place them on an axis $oX$, they would create an interval between $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, but would only unite if $1$ was part of $H$. Could that be where I'm supposed to be "heading" with my proof?

Comment: Well this is quite embarrassing, it was quite literally all I had to do. If 1 is in H, then from the 3rd property we have x=1/x for any x, and that is certainly not true, unless x is 1! Though I would still like to know how to formally explain the part with the "disconnected" intervals..

Comment: @EthanBolker the problem was translated from a different language, so perhaps they might have changed some things, but I've managed to find out a way to show it is not a uniform interval, as it is actually a reunion of two other intervals at best. I just now am trying to explain it formally, but cannot think of anything but to say that if a>1 is from H, then 0<1/a<1 is also from H, and if H were to be an interval, it would need to pass through 1, which I have managed to prove is not in H. Would this suffice?

Comment: in your comment you solved it - you know that $2032$ and $1/2023$ are in $H$ and $1$ is not (since, as you noticed it would have to be the only element of $H$), so $H$ is not an interval

Comment: @EthanBolker well how is it the identity element? " * " does not refer to the multiplication operation, its just a notation for the operation defined on H

Comment: @user8268 yeah, I've noticed that, i was asking for help and suddenly I realized what I had to do  thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: I misread the question, so am deleting my previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. It remains to show that $1 \not\in H$.

**Hint** Suppose otherwise. Then, the third property implies that for all $x \in H$, $1 \ast x = 1 \ast \frac1x$, hence $x = \frac1x$, so $x = 1$, i.e., $H = \{1\}$.

**Remark** Such a group actually exists: We can take $H := \Bbb R^+ \setminus \{1\}$ equipped with the operation $x \ast y := \exp(\log x \log y)$---which is just the multiplicative subgroup $(\Bbb R^\times, \cdot)$ of the field $\Bbb R$ conjugated by the (restriction) $\exp : \Bbb R^\times \to \Bbb R^+ \setminus \{1\}$ of the exponential map. The subgroup $(1, \infty) \subset H$ is connected, but it doesn't satisfy the second property.

Comment: Sir, I am not getting, how this shows that, $H$ is not an interval? Your hint just shows that, if $1\in H$ then $H=\{1\}$

Comment: The hint builds on OP's work: Since $2023$ is in $H$, so is $1/2023$, hence if $H$ is an interval...

Comment: By your last comment. If $H$ is an interval then it must contains $1$? Sir, correct me If I am wrong. (Here $1$ is identity in the group or the number $1\in (0, ∞)$? Or both are same?)

Comment: Correct, if an interval contains distinct points $a, b$, then it contains all points in between $a$ and $b$. Here $1$ is the element of $(0, \infty)$. The identity element is not determined by the three conditions. For the example in my remark, the identity is $e$.